# Determine if $\beta = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\beta = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$.
Suppose that all you know is that:

- $b_2$ is not a multiple of $b_3$.
- $b_1$ is not a linear combination of $b_2, b_3$.

Can you determine if $\beta$ is linearly independent?

From the second assumption, I think we can tell that $b_1$ isn't a multiple of $b_2$ nor $b_3$, Right?

So, All in all, we get that no vector is a multiple of the other.
With that in mind, can we figure that $\beta$ is linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three vectors can be linearly independent without each being strictly a multiple of one other. You *are* correct that the vectors are linearly independent.

Assuming $b_1, b_2, b_3$ are non-zero:

We start with the set $\{b_2, b_3\}$ where we know that $b_2$ and $b_3$ must be linearly independent, since one is not a multiple of the other. We know that vectors are linearly independent if any one of them cannot be written as  a linear combination of the others. In the case of *two* vectors, this essentially means that they are linearly independent if one is not equal to a multiple of the other.

We have $b_1$ and are given that $b_1$ is not a *linear combination* of $b_2 $ and $b_3$. That tells us that the addition of a vector that is linearly independent of two linearly independent vectors gives us a set of three linearly independent vectors $\;\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$.

Comment: appreciate your detailed answer. Thank you sir

Comment: You're welcome, Andre.

Comment: Apparently, someone down-voted you're answer. I don't know why though

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment?

Comment: I downvoted. Look at my answer...

Comment: @Andre No worries. There are some users, when they get upset, i.e., by a comment, retaliate by finding a post to downvote.

Comment: Yes, after I downvoted. And you miss the whole point of the question by doing that, in my opinion.

Comment: I upvoted the answer. The given information in THIS question does not lead me to suggest that any of the vectors could be a zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $b_1 = (1,0)$, $b_2 = (0,1)$ and $b_3 = (0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Are they linearly independent? Do they satisfy the hypotheses?

The common trap here is that two **nonzero** vectors are linearly independent iff the first is not a multiple of the second. When one of them is zero though...

Comment: I understand, @amWhy hypotheses is valid as long as $b_i \ne 0$. Thank you for this comment.